# Biblical prediction for Ashkenazi-Sepharadi split

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, nevua-prophecy

Is there any prediction in the Torah for the split between Ashkenazim and Sepharadim? I was told that there is but can't think of anywhere to look. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Also, please [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3346) to give yourself a name!

Comment: there is no split.

Comment: There's certainly no explicit prediction. (I've read the entire Pentateuch, and it doesn't mention such a thing explicitly.) I assume you're asking about either (1) an allusion (that someone, most likely post facto but maybe not, said alludes to the split between _Ashk'nazim_ and _S'faradim_) or (2) a generality (about how people will split or some such, that someone said applies to, inter alia, the split between _Ashk'nazim_ and _S'faradim_). Which?

Comment: Also, It is not clear that 'Sepharad' in the Book of Obadiah is a reference of Spaniard's Sephardi  http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1601.htm#20

Comment: What about Italian, Yemenite, Greek and Ethiopian Jews?

Comment: It's not a split. It's fragmentation. The divisions among religious Jews today are less neat and are more complex than simply "Ashkenazim" and "Sefaradim". Kol tuv.

Comment: There are DNA studies that suggest Ashkenazi and Sephardic Jews are more closely related than Ashkenazi Jews are to their host populations. Although there  appears to be a Roman origin (maternal)  to Ashkenazi Jews, those original three or four mothers reproduced with Middle Eastern Jewish men. One or two thousand years of Ashkenazi in-breeding with minimal admixture has strengthened  and reinforced the Ashkenazi ethnicity but it appears they retain most of their Near East origins as do Sephardim.

Comment: There's no split. They're different flavors of Judaism. Consider the Yud-Beis Shevatim, which each had a different "flavor" of Judaism.

Comment: @ezra the twelve tribes practiced the same religion. All stood at Sinai. All asked Moshe their questions. He presumably gave each the same answers.

Comment: In Sefer Ovadia (part of Trei Asar, the "12 'Minor' Prophets"),  (which is the Haftarah for Sedra VaYishlach) at the end, Pasuk 20, there is a prediction of 2 exiles, one for Zarephath (which is an allusion to France, close to Ashkenaz) and another exile to Sepharad (which is an allusion to Spain).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question can be adequately answered, because it's based on a false premise. There never was or is a "split" between Ashkenazim and Sepharadim. They are two different regional "flavors" of Judaism, and don't (or shouldn't) have emnity or difference in basic Jewish belief.

Not to mention that the terms "Ashkenazi" and "Sepharadi" are extremely broad - with the term Ashkenazi you could be speaking of German, Polish-Hungarian, Lithuanian, Ukrainian-Russian, and Italian Jewry, and with Sepharadi you could be speaking of Spanish-Portuguese or North African "flavors". Plus, far-eastern groups don't fit in either category, such as the Yemenites and Iraqi Jews, who would fall in the category of "Mizrahi".

If you look back in the times of Hazal, you'll see that there were different "flavors" of Judaism back then. Consider the differences between the communities in Judea versus Galilee, Rome, etc. Or if you go back even farther, consider how each tribe of Israel had a different "flavor" of Judaism.

So there has never been a "split", it's just that different practices have formed with Jews being spread out over the  face of the globe. Ashkenazim don't find it strange at all to pray with shoes on, because royalty was greeted with shoes on in Europe, but some Sepharadim and Mizrahim might take their shoes off!

Answer (score 0):

This is way below my usual standard, but I asked around and heard that people seem to think that [Bamidbar 24:5](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bemidbar/24.5#e0n7), מה טבו אהליך יעקב, can also be taken as a slight curse, and that in the future there will be many tents in Kelal Yisrael (a minimum of 2), and that refers to this split.  While I don't personally feel that this is a biblical prediction of such a split, it could be that this is what the person that told you was thinking of/referring to.

Comment: You expect 14 million people to share one tent?

Comment: I feel the same way, @ezra

Comment: I honestly don't know why this question exists, as it's based on a false premise that there is/was a "split" between Ashkenazim and Sephardim... There isn't a split, nor was there ever one. They're different regional flavors of Judaism, something we saw back in the times of Hazal (think of the differences between Galilee and Judea) or even older (each tribe had a different "flavor").

Comment: @ezra So why haven't you downvoted it?

Comment: I've mentioned elsewhere on this site that I don't downvote something unless I just really don't like it.

Comment: @ezra seems like this is exactly what downvoting is for...  Consider it.

Comment: @ezra indeed all Jews could use the same Sukkah (Sukkah 27b)

Comment: @DoubleAA I know you might be extremely worried, but Purim spirit _does_ wear off after a while. No need for alarm. It must be tough having to deal with post-Purim stupor.

Answer (score -1):

In my humble and purely theoretical understanding, a **real diametrical split** would be between **the Litvaks and the Hassidim**.

They represent two ways of serving Hashem, representing, respectively, "סור מרע" and "עשה טוב". In other terms, it is Din and Hessed, mind and body, brains and soul, Shabbos and weekdays etc respectively.

This differentiation can be traced back to the first Hassidim ("חסידים ראשונים" as in Mishna) that spent 9 hours a day in prayers (as described in Brochos), up to a point when the Gemmorah wonders "how do they learn Torah at all?". An interesting observation is naming convention of the Gdoylim in both communities: **Litvakes calling them "Geoynim"**, putting the weight on the brains, while **Hassidim call them "Kadosh"** (כבוד קדושת), emphasizing the purity of the soul. This can be clearly seen in Brochos (34b) on the difference between R' Yochanan Ben Zakay and R' Haninah Ben Dosah "אלא הוא דומה כעבד לפני המלך, ואני דומה כשר לפני המלך".

Therefore, I conclude that those two approaches are intrinsic to Judaism. To Sefardim, on the other hand, being attracted mainly to leveling between the two, I would address **the middle line which is Tifferes**.

Answer (score -2):

Not specifically to Sepharadim/Ashkenazi split, but there is a derivation of "**flock**" from “Ha’emet Tiheye **Ne’ederet**” that during the times before the advent of Moshiach, Jews will be split.
From a discussion on [Devarim](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/WeeklyParasha.asp?ParashaClipID=363)

> The Gemara describes certain negative qualities that will characterize
>   the generation before the arrival of Mashiah, one of them being
>   “Ha’emet Tiheye Ne’ederet.” Literally, this means that “truth will be
>   obscured,” meaning, truths that should be and always had been obvious
>   and self-evident will become questionable. In our times, for example,
>   low standards of modesty and integrity which would have been rejected
>   without a second thought generations ago are now considered valid
>   options. This is one manifestation of “Ha’emet Tiheye Ne’ederet.”
>   Additionally, however, the term “Ne’ederet” refers to the phenomenon
>   of “Eder” – “flock.” The Jewish people will form small, independent
>   “flocks” that stay away from one another. Each “flock” will follow its
>   “shepherd,” its Rabbi, and show no respect or regard for anything
>   else. The prevailing attitude will be one of “It’s my way, or you’re
>   out!” There will be little or no tolerance for differing views and
>   opinions.

Comment: The Gemara is Sotah 49b ויראי חטא ימאסו והאמת תהא נעדרת נערים פני זקנים ילבינו it is not a verse in Devarim, nor anywhere else to the best of my knowledge. Furthermore as noted, this does not appear to be the intent of the Gemara's usage.

Comment: @mevaqesh He said it was a discussion on Devarim, not that it was specifically referring to that passuk. The article is very clear about what is the passuk and what is the Gemara.

Comment: The question was about the Torah. The fact that the article is supposedly about the Torah, and supposedly also about the question obscures the fact that the question was about the Torah discussing the split which this post provides no evidence of. Additionally nothing in the gemara, let alone the Torah is even relevant to the question. The only part ever remotely relevant is the misinterpretation of a word in a gemara, by an unknown author.